# JS: Destructure an object into another with renamed properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, destructuring

Is it possible to do something like the following in JS?

```
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

const copyObj = {...{ a: x, b: y, c: z } = obj };
```

I'm aware that I can do this:

```
const { a: x, b: y, c: z } = obj;

const copyObj = { x, y, z };
```

but it's not what I want. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you cannot use the 2nd one ?

Comment: You can also do `const {a, b, c} = obj; const copyObj = {x: a, y: b, z: c};`

Comment: @Dilshan It's not that I cannot/will not use it, I just wonder if there's a more "dry" approach to this. It's kind of a curiosity-driven/theoretical question.

Comment: @Bergi I'm aware of this approach and I've mentioned it in my question's description.

Comment: @GenesisAlgorithms The only way not to repeat the property names is the trivial `const copyObj = {x: ob.a, y: obj.b, z: obj.c};`. It really doesn't become simpler than that.

Comment: Yea, I know this too... but I was just curious if there's some syntax "trickery" which could enable me to do what I wanted. Anyways, thanks! I now know the answer at least :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a function for getting wanted and renamed properties.

```js
const
    rename = ({ a: x, b: y, c: z }) => ({ x, y, z }),
    obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
    copyObj = rename(obj);

console.log(copyObj);
```

Comment: Thanks! I would probably not use this but it's still a valid answer to my question.

Comment: it is a pattern which does not create (superfluous) variables outside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an inline style using [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

const copyObj = { ...(({ a: x, b: y, c: z }) => ({ x, y, z }))(obj) }

console.log(copyObj)
```

Comment: the function returns already a new object. spreading is not necessary.